# Separate migration jar - flyway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

We use flyway migration along with spring boot and Gradle.

I wanted to have separate jar for migration. As It was required to run migrations manually without being run automatically on app startup and without installing any tool.

The reason being multiple web servers pointing to same database may cause race condition when running migrations.

I came across this FAQ, PARALLEL , can I get bit more details, so that I can live with running the migrations on app startup.

Comment: *multiple web servers pointing to same database may cause race condition when running migrations*: no, that should not happen, because Flyway takes care of that.

Comment: Thank you for that, but wanted to know how ...

Comment: As the FAQ indicates (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#parallel): *Flyway uses the locking technology of your database to coordinate multiple nodes.*